# Display image in notes form from another database

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus, lotusscript, lotus-formula

In a traditional notes form, I want to compute an image dynamically. Image is in another database's image resource in the same server.

I have tried using pass thru HTML by computing the URL in computed text. Its working fine in web. But I need to show the form in Notes Client. I am using the client version 8.5.2.

In computing URL I have tried using *notes://* instead of *http://.* Still no luck.
If anybody help me to find out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the computed image resource doesn't like implied text construction, I tried to do exactly as you building the image string and it kept failing until I did this:

@Text(@GetField("from") + ".jpg")

I used a combo box "from" to test with "refresh on keyword change" to simulate a new value.  The images changed beautifully and the resource was selected from a different database.

One thing to watch for, that I was unaware of, is if you create an image resource and import a .bmp (bitmap) image, it's changed to an .jpg.  This could mess you up by trying to reference a non existing image.

In short, a computed image resource from a different database will work.

Comment: Thanks... It works fine.. Sorry I missed out @Text... But the empcode is also a text field... Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

While inserting image resource you can select the database from which the image needs to be loaded. So when you go to "Create > Image Resource" you can select "Database" field and then the images in that database.

Comment: Its fine for one time embedding or static/single images. But I need to compute dynamically depends on the current user. When I am seeing on the picture properties in formula window for computing, it is showing only the image name eventhough it if from another database. Still I didn't find any solution.

Comment: @KarthickMoorthy: I am afraid there is no option in Image Resource to compute the database path.

Comment: Please find the tip from "user2409403" above. It will give us some idea. When were are inserting an image resource from another database, that image is tied with that database. And in its properties if you just change the image name which exists in 2nd database, it will display the image. But we cannot compute the image name from any field. In that computed property we need to return only the text (hardcoded image name). It will not get from any other field.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is insert an image resource. Place your cursor on the form where you want the dynamic picture, right mouse click and select "insert resource".  Once the "Insert Recource" dialog displays select the database where the image resources are stored and the select the "Images" Resource type. You will have to select an image, probably make it your default image and click "OK".

Next, click on the image to give it focus and then either do an "alt + Enter" or right click and select "Picture Properties".  When the picture properties display you'll see at the far right of the "Source" field two icons, select the second "@" for the formula window, this is where the magic is done.  You'll see the current image name is already there.  All you do now is create your @If statements to change the image name, no paths just the image name, the resource is already tied to the database where your images are stored.  This has been long but actually implementing is quick and simple.  enjoy:-)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes this way is excellent. But in the computation of formula I have to return only text, It will not accept field value. Here I want to show employee photo where all photo were stored in another database and with empcode as file name. In my form I am having empcode but I am unable to show their image. How can I achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Karthick,

I'm not sure if this is your issue but remember the order of how your form is processed, left to right and top down.  If the field with your empcode is positiond after the image resource, the formula won't see the field value, unless you do a refresh. I used a field that contained the value to check to switch my images and that worked.  Have you tried @GetField("the field name") to return the value?

Comment: Thanks for you response. Order of the fields were perfect. As per your previous tip, I tried to computed the image. It works if the image is in the current database. But not working for other database.

Comment: I will explain you what I have tried. [No. 1.] I have inserted an image resource from the current database in the end of the form. And computed the image name as follows. ---> empcode + ".jpg" <---. where empcode is the name of the field and have the value of employee code, say 10001. And the image is stored in the current database in the name of 10001.jpg. This works fine. Where you said like the inserted image resource is tied with current database. [No. 2.] I have inserted an another image resource from another database, not a current database and proceeded the same. But its not helping me.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do it in direct way. You can neither compute the database nor pass the other db's image url. When inserting resource, it will ask for database name. if you choose the name as "a". Then the image resource will adopt to the database what you have chosen. It will take the images from the db "a". It will not take the image from current DB. So you just pass the image file name simply.

Use formula like this.,

```
@If(@GetField("pic")="1";"spinning earth.gif";@GetField("pic") = "3";"logo.jpg";"attach2.jpg")
```

The mentioned three picture is coming from different database but same server. If you want to fetch the image from current db then use another image resource. Make hide when. squeeze your brian.

Answer (score 0):

The computed image resource as described in the other solutions will for sure work. 
The only "problem" is, that the designer wants to get a text pointing to a valid file when saving the form. Otherwise it will render the image unusable.

Knowing that and knowing, that field- values are considered empty in the designer client, you have to "wrap" your result in an if- clause, or break out of computation, if the needed field is empty. Your first line could look like:

```
@If( FieldWithImageName = ""; @Return( "myfallbackimage.jpg" ); "" );
```

After that you do your computation. designer will fallback to the fallback- image, and the client will compute the image based on your formula, if the field that you refer to is above the image (you know: left to right, top to bottom computation of forms)

Another thing to notice: in earlier versions of Lotus Notes the image just scaled to its own 100% size, when you seleced 100% in the image properties. But in 7 (iirc) this changed, and all images are displayed with the number of pixels the image in designer was stored. If your fallback- image is 100x100 pixels, then every image will be squeezed or stretched to that extends. So better be sure, all images have the same size.